# Приходят разные данные, грубо говоря, из одного и того же файла

Tags: java, android

В общем, есть 2 метода. Один - читает данные с clipboard'a, второй - из текстового документа. Вывожу оба в Toast'e - приходят одинаковые значения. (world - world, к примеру), а если сделать условие с тем, что данные равны - условие не выполняется. 
Сам код, собственно:

```
public void readFromoRAM(){
    data = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
    if (data !=null) {
        ClipData.Item items = data.getItemAt(0);
        posts = items.getText().toString();
    }
}

private void readTXT() {
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + fileNametwo);
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            getstwo=String.valueOf(stringBuilder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

P.S Если, допустим, cделать такое условие - оно не выполнится:

```
if (posts == getstwo){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Значения равны.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Что за бред? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Строки в Java по значению надо сравнивать через `equals`. Используя `==`, вы сравниваете ссылки.

Comment: Хм... А как это сделать в этом примере? Не подскажите?

Comment: `if (posts.equals(getstwo)){...`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Мучился 5 часов...

Comment: И ещё одно... На этот раз точно последние) Если не затруднит, то какой аналог у if (posts != getstwo)?

Comment: `if (!posts.equals(getstwo)){...`

Comment: Всё так просто?... Спасибо. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @woesss странно, кстати, недавно эксперементировал даже с pure java и двойное равенство возвращало мне true. Ведь строки хранятся в какой то хештаблице, и мапятся, если одинаковые. Хотя да, equals однозначно надёжнее

Comment: Дубликат посмотрите там расписано в каких случаях это работает.